# Is there anyway to always allow all cameras and microphones in firefox?

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I've got a page using WebRTC to display video and audio chat.  The users each have multiple cameras/audio sources and need to be able to change between them freely.  In Chrome, once I select allow it allows all devices but in Firefox always allow only allows the currently selected devices.  The only way to get all devices is to have them click allow on the dialogue every time they change cameras.

Comment: That's not true. "Always allow" in Firefox applies to all devices. Try it here https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/devices/input-output/

Comment: ok thanks let me look at the example and see what is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an "always allow" option in Firefox in the drop-down list (if your site is using https)